# Where are git database files stored on windows?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I've installed git, created a rep, checked in and made changes to some files but I want to know where git stores the repo db and the master files so I can back them up.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git saves everything (local to your current repository) in the `.git` folder.

An extensive description can be found [on gitready](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html) for example.

2 of them you are probably interested in:

> - objects: Git’s internal warehouse of blobs, all indexed by SHAs.
> - refs: The master copy of all refs that live in your repository, be they for stashes, tags, remote tracking branches, or local branches.

For backups or transferring your local repository, zipping or copying your *.git* folder is enough.

Comment: But when you "Commit" your changes before pushing, is everything being saved in the .git folder as well? I've made my first commit of an already existing project, consisting of the whole project, and the .git folder seems to be very small

Comment: Yes, local commits are saved into the `.git` folder as well. Yes, git is very size efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It `\.git\` is set as a hidden folder, so you do need to adjust your Explorer display settings to show the 'hidden' files.

Answer (score 0):

For backup purposes, I use

```
git clone --bare --mirror <url to repository>
```

and then a script that nightly executes

```
git fetch origin -q
git remote prune origin
```

This will create a git-repository without workingdirectories (thus only databases) and updates it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

One of Git's features as a [distributed version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) is that - unlike, say, Subversion - every working copy of a project is itself a repository containing the complete history of the project.

Git's files are in the hidden `.git` folder in the project root. This means you can back up the repository just by backing up the folder you initialised your project in, and you can delete the repository just by deleting the `.git` folder.